# Cell border not showing in IE9 when filter gradient is applied to cells

Tags: html, css, filter, internet-explorer-9

I'm creating a grid list, using a CSS gradient applied in the title row, i.e. the first row. Also there is border applied.

Before applying the Gradient filter the border was showing in all browsers, but after applied the gradient filter, IE hides the border! Others browsers are ok.

CSS code below:

```
.list tr.titlerow, .list .titlerow th {
    border: 1px solid #a0a0a0;
    height:25px;
    padding:2px;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr='#EBEBEB', endColorstr='#ffffff');/*For IE7-8-9*/  
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #EBEBEB 0%, #fff 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#EBEBEB), color-stop(100%,#fff)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #EBEBEB 0%,#fff 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #EBEBEB 0%,#fff 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #EBEBEB 0%,#fff 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */


}
```

Can anyone please help me to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

IE filters can often completely mess up other things for no good reason. Sometimes applying one filter kills another filter - they don't even play nicely with each other, let alone proper CSS!

Instead of using a filter and trying to do things the proper way, I would just fall back to an image-based gradient for IE using conditional comments or some other similar mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

Try this way:-

```
    .list tr.titlerow, .list .titlerow th
    {
        border: 1px solid #a0a0a0;
        height:25px;
        padding:2px;
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #EBEBEB 0%, #fff 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#EBEBEB), color-stop(100%,#fff)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #EBEBEB 0%,#fff 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #EBEBEB 0%,#fff 100%); /* IE10+ */
        background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #EBEBEB 0%,#fff 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ 
*/
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr='#EBEBEB', endColorstr='#ffffff'); /* IE6 & IE7 */ 
        -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr='#EBEBEB', endColorstr='#ffffff')";    /* IE8 */ 

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add position:relative;

```css
.container 
{
    display: table;
    background-color: lightblue;
    border-spacing: 5px 0;
}

.container > a
{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 60px;
    height: 25px;   
   
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    
 border-color:#adae9c;
 background: #e4e7dd; /* Old browsers */
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #fefefe 0%, #e4e7dd 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
 background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#fefefe), color-stop(100%,#e4e7dd)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #fefefe 0%,#e4e7dd 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
 background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #fefefe 0%,#e4e7dd 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
 background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #fefefe 0%,#e4e7dd 100%); /* IE10+ */
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #fefefe 0%,#e4e7dd 100%); /* W3C */

    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fefefe',endColorstr='#e4e7dd',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    /*get around bug with IE9 that won't render the border if combined with table-cell and using a filter*/
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
    <a>test1</a>
    <a>test2</a>
</div>
```